# Replace Divs innerHTML with external html site

Tags: javascript, html

I have three Links:

```
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" onclick="changeSite('all.html')">All</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" onclick="changeSite('new.html')">New</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" onclick="changeSite('random.html')">Random</a>
    </div>
```

How you can see on `onclick` the function `changeSite` is triggered:

```
var changeSite = function(pathName){
    document.getElementById("siteContent").innerHTML = 
}
```

With the help of this function i would like to replace the content of the div with the id `siteContent`, to either the content of `all.html, new.html` or `random.html`. These three sites are in the same Folder like my `index.html` where the code is actually triggered. How can i set the `.innerHTML` to the content of one of this sites? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optional: When you say 'external site' it usually means that the resources are hosted on a server different from the one that serves the initial page. Your external server needs to be configured to either support [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) or respond with proper [CORS headers](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) to allow for cross-site ajax.

Then you can use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to request the data from the site, and place it into your template.

You can use jQuery, but it's pretty straightforward without it:

```
var changeSite = function(pathName) {
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("siteContent").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
  r.open('get', pathName, true);
  r.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the jquery load function allows you to specify an element id to load

```
$('#<id to load html to>').load('xyz.html');
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/